# complex analysis: image of axes

Tags: complex-analysis

Given is following function
$$w=f(z)=\frac{2z-1}{2-z}, z=x+iy,w=u+iv$$
where $i$ is the imaginary unit.
Task is to determine the image of the imaginary axis. The solution calculates the inverse function and finds for x
$$x=\frac{2u^2+5u+2v^2+2}{(u+2)^2+v^2}$$
which is fine with me.By setting $x=0$ one gets 
$$(u+\frac{5}{4})^2+v^2=(\frac{3}{4})^2$$
which is obviously describes a circle.

Problem is: When I did it, I decided to solve for u and v, which got me
$$u=\frac{-2x^2+5x-2y^2-2}{(2-x)^2+y^2}$$
$$v=\frac{3y}{(2-x)^2+y^2}$$

Then I set $x=0$ which then got me $u$ and $v$, depending only on $y$:
$$u=\frac{-2y^2-2}{4+y^2}$$
$$v=\frac{3y}{4+y^2}$$
Putting then $u$ and $v$ back together I again, I thought that $w$ now should be a circle if plotted (it isn't). Additionally, if the image of the imaginary axis is a circle, the absolute value of $w=u+iv$ with $x=0$ should be constant; as it turned out, it isn't (or I miscalculated it a few times). Now that seems odd to me so I'd very much appreciate it if somebody could enlighten/correct me.

Thanks!

Comment: i plotted you parametric $u,v$ with $y$ as the parameter. i got a circle.

Comment: well you're right - I plotted it carefully and it indeed looks like it's a circle - and after thinking about i.e. $f(t)=(cos(t),sin(t)+5)$ which of course is a circle but doesn't have a constant norm; And of course it doesn't have since not every point hast the same distance to (0,0) (that only applies for zero-centered circles not that I think about it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking again I realised that only zero-centered circles have constant absolute value, and plotting it again carefully did indeed show a circle, so I guess that's it.